# unable to fire change event on select list

Tags: javascript, html

html:

```
<select id="v_name" align="top">
  <option value="server1">server1</option>
  <option value="server2">server2</option>

    </select>
```

javascript:

```
<script>

  $("#v_name").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val(); //value of selected attribute
 alert(selected);
  });
</script>
```

When I change the selected item on the select, alert is not firing. Any ideas

Comment: Put script after html.

Comment: Move it in document ready. Working example http://jsfiddle.net/2Ld4yg44/

Comment: tank you both, I should've known that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is OK you just have to make sure the element exists in the DOM before the script executes.

Put it inside document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#v_name").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val(); //value of selected attribute
        alert(selected);
    });

});
```

Working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/y2jppe6m/